# Running PiHole with Apache2

Tags: apache-http-server, raspbian, pihole

I'm trying to install PiHole on my Raspberry Pi, but having some trouble configuring it. I currently use it as a reverse proxy to some webservers/applications running in my network. My main issue (I think) is because I use Cloudflare, I need to use port 80 (since I can't specify an A record with a port).

So I'm hoping there is some way of replacing lighttpd with my existing Apache instance. What I would like to do:

- Keep Cloudflare pointing at my static IP address, so port 80 will hit my reverse proxy
- Configure my router to use the local IP of my Raspberry PI (192.168.xxx.xxx) as the DNS server

Here is my current vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@address.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@address.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ServerName subdomain2.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias subdomain2.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.xxx.xxx:9000/
</VirtualHost>

<!-- A few more entries with different ports/subdomains -->

I'm currently running PiHole in a docker container, but that can be changed if required. I've made no configuration changes to PiHole.

Thanks!
```

Comment: It's not very clear to me what the actual question is....? Seems your apache vhost config is good already.

Comment: For computers/devices in my local network, how would I set my DNS server to the Pi? In Windows when I try and update my DNS server, it requires an IP address, not an IP address with a port. If the PiHole is not running on port 80 (which it can't due to Apache2 using it), what IP address can I set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how DNS works. DNS always works on port 53 (UDP/TCP). Anything you're doing with the reverse proxy or Cloudflare will only work for HTTP protocol (such as the PiHole web server, used to configure and monitor PiHole). The PiHole DNS service will *only* work on port 53.

If you want to use PiHole on your local network, set the DNS settings on devices in your network to the IP address of your Pi.

If you want to use your PiHole across the internet, read a couple of guides on the dangers of running an open resolver on the internet.

Comment: Hi @mtak, I think you've clarified exactly what I needed. I wasn't aware DNS always goes through port 53, and was confusing it with the admin UI on port 80. :)